# UIImage in UITableviewcell layout

Tags: uitableview

I have a problem layout the objects in the code.
Here is a picture of current and desired status:

[image]

And here is the code

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];    
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"My Favorites", @"My Favorites");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];

}    

favoritesTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 364) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[favoritesTable setHidden:NO];
[favoritesTable setDelegate:self];
[favoritesTable setDataSource:self];

[self.view addSubview:favoritesTable];        

[favoritesTable release];

return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"<#MyCell#>";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSInteger objectLocation = indexPath.row;

FoodData* food = (FoodData*)[resultsArray objectAtIndex:objectLocation];    

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paris.jpg"];
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(270, 4, 40, 36);    

cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;

UILabel* lblText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 20)];
UILabel* lblType = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 21, 260, 20)];

[lblText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0]];
[lblType setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9.0]];

lblType.textColor = [UIColor blueColor  ];

[lblText setText:[food foodName]];
[lblType setText:[food foodType]];

[cell addSubview:lblText];
[cell addSubview:lblType];

[lblText release];
[lblType release];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on ios5, making use of the prototype cell on the IB will be the easiest way out for you.

if you are not on ios 5, i do highly recommending using a custom tableviewcell.

The short solution to your issue can be found here in the link below.

[UITableViewCell with image on the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780395/uitableviewcell-with-image-on-the-right)

Comment: I did with UIImageView but them I couldn't catch its ontouch event. you can see here my last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029049/catch-uiimageviewe-touch-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: hmmm... Seems like you are asking only part of your requirements. will be great if you could update your problem including what you intend to achieve. But i dont think you will have problem adding a event to the uiImage. I will check if out when i get my hands on a mac.